# how to avoid strange tortoise behaviour

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

i am using tortoise since a couple of years. (the current tortoise installation was made in approx. october 2013) anyway, today was the first time when renaming two files with tortoise in the windows explorer - 2 .cpp & 2 .h files.

subsequent, a commit was tried but tortoise required the old files in addition. obviously, they were not available.
(from another directory, old versions of the files (with old filenames) were copied)
with old files, a commit was possible - tortoise mentioned 'replacing' concerning the old files (in the commit dialog) but the old files were still there after the commit. with the tortoise context menu, the old files were removed and another commit was made (to remove old files for other developers - cleanup).

why is a 'rename' option provided within tortoise when it does not work (for already committed files)? has anybody an experience with this issue?

edit: from my experience gained today, a possibility would be using the windows explorer to create copies of files, renaming these copies, tortoise delete for the old files, tortoise add for the newer files (copies) and a tortoise commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rename in svn is handled as an add for the new name, and a delete for the old name.
Since the old named file isn't there anymore, you have to commit the parent folder of the renamed file: then the commit dialog shows both the deleted and added files: you have to commit both in the same commit.

Comment: tnx - have to do an additional renaming of files next week - then, your answer will be accepted. currently, +1